# How can I use a SQL query result as a column in another query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a view that returns weekday. The result will be a column in WHERE clause, something like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM dvtv_delivery WHERE (SELECT day FROM dvtv_weekday) = 'Y'
```

For example:

Today is sunday, in dvtv_weekday returns SUN
In dvtv_delivery  exist the column SUN

Is it possible in Mysql? When I run nothing appears

Using I use down below, works

```
  SELECT * FROM dvtv_delivery WHERE SUN = 'Y'
```

Any answer would really be helpful!
Sorry my bad English

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Your query should execute successfully, although it might not do what you really want.

Comment: You need a column in `dvtv_delivery` table to have an association with `dvtv_weekday` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT day FROM dvtv_weekday
```

returns a string like `'SUN'` and not the name of the column `SUN`.
So WHERE is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 'SUN' = 'Y'
```

which will always return no rows. 
You need something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dvtv_delivery 
WHERE 
  CASE (SELECT day FROM dvtv_weekday) 
    WHEN 'SUN' THEN SUN
    WHEN 'MON' THEN MON
    WHEN 'TUE' THEN TUE
    WHEN 'WED' THEN WED
    WHEN 'THU' THEN THU
    WHEN 'FRI' THEN FRI
    WHEN 'SAT' THEN SAT
  END = 'Y'
```

I assume that the table `dvtv_delivery` has all these columns: `SUN, MON, ....`

Answer (score 0):

> The result will be a column in WHERE clause

If that's the case (you want to compare a column), that column should be part of the same query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM dvtv_delivery
WHERE
    day = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query, as written will execute, assuming that the subquery returns exactly one row:

```
SELECT *
FROM dvtv_delivery
WHERE (SELECT day FROM dvtv_weekday) = 'Y'
```

Such a query is a *scalar subquery*.  It must return one column and at most one row (under most circumstances).

Often, such subqueries are *correlated* to the outer query.  That means that a `WHERE` clause connects values in the two tables.  It is not clear what a correlation clause would look like in this case, but the structure of the query is:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM dvtv_delivery d
WHERE (SELECT wd.day
       FROM dvtv_weekday wd
       WHERE wd.? = d.?  -- maybe these would be date columns?
      ) = 'Y'
```